# ngx-infinite-scroll with percentage height does not appear

Tags: html, css, angular

On an Angular 4 project, I don't get the scrolling bar to appear on screen.

When I use absolute size like `height: 70rem`, it works fine, just doesn't fit my app in which the list changes in size.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="row" style="height: 90%; overflow-y:scroll"
  infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"  [scrollWindow]=false 
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="500" (scrolled)="onScroll()">
  <div *ngFor="let server of servers">
    <span> {{ server }} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of "height: 90%" use "height: 90vh". it might be work.